# Springs @EnableOauth2Sso basic example gives 403-errorpages an all routes

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

To be fair, i first asked this question in the official [GitHub-Repository](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/sso/issues/10) of the example-project. However since i didn't get an answer for one week now, i felt that stackoverflow might be a better place to ask. I'll do my best to keep findings and updates in synch beetween these threads, so that the efforts made at one place or another are shared.

I am charged with the task to migrate a Oauth2 single sign on system to an inherited Spring-project. Therefore i decided to go with [Spring Cloud Security](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-security/). Sadly i cannot even get the [most basic example](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/sso) to work, that is shipped together with Spring Cloud itself. I cloned the project from GitHub to my desktop and then run it from eclipse. I tried to run it with different arguments, to choose between different profiles: the official github-profile, which is included already, and a custom profile for our own oauth2-authentication-server. But all i can get are 403-errorpages on all routes. Here are some example urls, i tried out:

- http://localhost:8080/
- http://localhost:8080/dashboard/
- http://localhost:8080/dashboard/login
- http://localhost:8080/resources/static/index.html
- http://localhost:8080/foo/bar (non-existent fantasy url)

Obviously i must have missed some instructions, but i don't know where to look. The console-output does not show any meaningfull messages, in particular there are no warnings and errors, this suggests that the application is running just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Shame on me, i tried to reproduce the error on a different machine with a different eclipse-version installed. It turned out that my *run configuration* has been set up in a wrong way. Deleting it and setting up a new *run configuration* solved the problem.